# WCF service with several methods, log the raw request that came in from the client regardless

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I need an example in WCF..

I want a WCF service with several methods. I would like to log the raw request that came in from the client regardless of how this was sent and convert in proper SOAP XML request.

Can anybody provide me full example.

Answer (score 1):

Using message inspector (like suggested above) will give you the logical message. This is different than the raw message since the latter may contain extra security/wsa tags, the namespace prefixes might be different and of course the size. It may also be partially encrypted so you might not see everything (depend on your binding). So it depends which message you want to get. If the logical is good enough use a [message inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx). If you want the real raw message then either implement a [custom message encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx) to get it from there or [read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) about wcf logging and instead of System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener put your own class that implements the interface.